# Web Audio Api JavaScriptAudioNode and number of channels

Tags: audio, google-chrome, webkit, w3c, chromium

I'm currently playing with [Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html).

I have a mono synthesizer of my creation in javascript, so I created a `JavaScriptAudioNode` element with 0 inputs and 1 output, conected with the `audioDestinationNode` of my context.

Everytime the process function is called, i call
`event.outputBuffer.getChannelData` and pass the output channel array to
my synth. Being my synth mono, it expects only one channel (array),
but JavaScriptAudioNode actually comes with two channels per output.
so i can "fill" only the left or the right channel, depending if i
call `getChannelData(0)` or `(1)`.

is there a way to have a mono `JavaScriptAudioNode` element? If not, is
there a way to automatically "upmix" my mono channel into two stereo
channels?

(yeah, I could do it by hand, with a weighted addition, but laziness is the greatest virtue).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, it will create a node with 0 inputs and 1 output.

```
node = context.createJavaScriptNode(<BUFFER_SIZE>, 0, 1),
```